# How to copy a folder like /usr in a preserving manner?

Tags: bash, permissions

I need to preserve owners, groups, and permissions, but also soft and hard links.

As far as I can see there are two cases to discern:

1. Links within the folder structure to copy, like `lrwxrwxrwx /usr/foo/bar` to `/usr/bar`
2. Links pointing outside the folder structure, like `lrwxrwxrwx /usr/baz/dev/tty0` to `/dev/tty0`

I need to do this on a Linux system.

Comment: I think `tar` will be your friend here

Comment: Possibly using the --preserve flag... `cp --preserve=all <src> <dest>`

Answer (score 2):

Read manual on `rsync`. Rsync is your friend when you want to preserve attributes.

Basically something like `rsync -lHAXogtE` should be (more than) enough, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`cp -a` (or `cp --archive`) is the usual approach for this kind of task; it preserves all attributes (ownership, permissions and extended attributes), and doesn't dereference links. It also copies recursively (like `-R`).

Comment: Thank you for your hint, - sorry - it should correctly be `cp -RP` but in practice there is no difference as `-H` copies all symlinks encountered during tree traversal. Together with the POSIX `-R` that does not read from other special files but copies the file type, you get the same effect as with the non-standard `-a`.